# How to build a model that maps strings to lists of strings?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, matching, sequence-analysis

I have a mapping from strings to rows in a data table. Each strings maps to exactly one row in a table but the opposite is not generally true (one row can be "bound" to different strings. For example we have the following row in the table:

```
| 1.2 | Box Set | 137 | Destiny Corporation | New York |
```

And there is a string that maps to this table row:

```
"NY_Dest.Corp.-137"
```

The same row is also represented by the following string:

```
"New-York_DestinyCorporation137"
```

The goal is to build a model that maps a string into corresponding row. In other words, given a string, we want to know what row corresponds to it.

My approach is to represent each row by a list of strings (each string is the value that is stored in a corresponding column). So, we need to define a model that maps strings to a list of strings. Or, alternatively, we need to calculate a score that tells us how well a given string match a given list of strings.

**ADDED**

I have just realized that the problem can be also formulated as a sequence matching problem. We can represent a list of strings as a string. For example `"| 1.2 | Box Set | 137 | Destiny Corporation | New York |"`. Then each string is, in fact, a sequence of symbols. So, we need to determine how well to sequences mach each other.

Comment: Have you investigated "hashing" algorithms? They are designed to avoid "collisions" when mapping objects to slots in a data structure.

Comment: @Bey, no I did not investigate that. What does it do exactly? Or how can I find information about that? Does it solve my problem?

Comment: Here's the wiki article on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table. Basically, they take a"key" (string in your case), and associate it with a location in an array (you can call them "rows" if you want..). It's a broad area, but I think it may give you ideas.